# Are there any philosophers who contemplated the nature of questions?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Are there any philosophers who contemplated the nature of questions as an object of conception themselves and studied their possible aims?

Comment: See [Questions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/questions/).

Comment: See [Hintikka’s Theory of Questions](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-009-3763-5_8) and J.Hintikka, [Socratic Epistemology](https://books.google.it/books?id=WcDUMaSc7osC)

Comment: The study of questions is called [erotetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erotetics), but I am not sure why this is asked here rather than on Philosophy SE.

Comment: @conifold I was hoping that earlier philosophers pondered about it or something closely related to it. Do you know if some ancient philosopher said something about it?

Comment: Not explicitly. Dialectical debates were structured as games of asking and answering questions (*elenchus*), [Socratic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method) is based on that, Aristotle discusses *elenchus* in Sophistical Refutations and other places, his four causes are sometimes interpreted as types of answers to "why" questions. Hintikka references Aristotle in his erotetics as an inspiration, see e.g. [The fallacy of fallacies](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00136775).

Answer (score 1):

Even those who indulged in erotetics would be trying to get answers to each of their enquiry/question.  Nobody would contemplate on questions only.  So, in my opinion good philosophers must have contemplated the nature of question also in deep.  They must have done it quickly because they wanted answers.  If you could go through the Upanishads you would have astonished how they tried to find these answers. They must have asked so many counter questions and on questions also.  So, what I mean is most great philosophers must have contemplated the nature of questions.  If you can't admit this, you had better explore erotetics.